# confusion about aseembly process register

Tags: assembly

I just started learning assembly and it may seem like a dumb question but i am actually confused about this .
I was wondering if there are multiple of each process register, lets say eax or ebx.From what i understand the register is used globally and there seem to be only 1?(eax and not eax1 or eax2 is used throughout the application from what i see when i disassembled my application)

But if there is 1 then wont there be data problem or some similar problem?Also wouldnt it be more efficient if there were more of these like eax1,eax2,eax3 .

Comment: What does "won't there be a data problem" mean? You should think about the problem until you have a precise question in mind, ideally with an example of what you think could go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one set of registers, and depending on which process is currently running, the right values will be swapped in and out. Swapping the registers is called a [context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) and does impart a performance cost.

While a single process is running, when it runs out of registers to store data, the values must be stored in memory until they are needed again. This will happen a lot, especially across function calls.

Different architectures will have a different numbers of registers. For example, RISC based processors typically have more registers to work with (although it isn't all a free gain as you *need* more due to the instruction set which is used). For a concrete sample, the Xbox360  which run on a PowerPC RISC based chip has 32 general purpose registers plus a handful of specific ones (instruction pointer, etc).

Modern Intel/AMD x64 based chips **do** have more registers as well (SSE, etc), but it will depend on your compiler whether or not it can take advantage of them and for what purpose (as their intent is more focused).